# How to do multiple histograms/bar charts related to two columns in python?

Tags: python, plot, histogram

I have a dataset with multiple rows and columns. Simplifying:

```
A   B   

g   1    
h   2   
h   3   
g   3   
j   4   
g   5
```

Where A is a code for a surgery and B is the length of stay in a hospital. So, each of the rows corresponds to a patient.

I would like to do multiple plots (one for each category) of columns A and B. In this example:

Plot 1: One plot where the x represents every patient, that went under a "g" surgery and the y represents the lenght of stay of each patient. So for this plot, must exist 3 bars, since there are 3 patients with "g" surgery;

Plot 2: One plot where the x represents every patient, that went under a "h" surgery and the y represents the lenght of stay of each patient. So for this plot, must exist 2 bars, since there are 2 patients with "h" surgery;

Plot 3: One plot where the x represents every patient, that went under a "j" surgery and the y represents the lenght of stay of each patient. So for this plot, must exist 1 bars, since there are 1 patients with "j" surgery;

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, get dataset in pandas as df:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['g', 'h', 'h', 'g', 'j', 'g'], 'B':[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]})
>>> df
   A  B
0  g  1
1  h  2
2  h  3
3  g  3
4  j  4
5  g  5
>>> df.groupby('A').plot(kind = 'bar')
A
g    AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
h    AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
j    AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
dtype: object
>>> plt.show()   #you'll see 3 different figures for that.
```

Comment: Yes, I understand! If I have three columns (A, B and C), in order to do exactly the same thing, how can I select only "A" and "B" columns in the plot? I only did, df_n=df[['A','B']], and then applied the groupy and plot to that df_n. But there is a faster way, right?

Comment: @bonaqua thats fine.  or just do: `df[['A', 'B']].groupby('A').plot(kind = 'bar')`